# Creating a List - Creating one more level of list than wanted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am able to successfully add to a list called `donnes` elements from a list called `liste_dominos`. However, it seems like I'm creating an extra level in the list.

While printing `donnes`, instead of having this output :

`[[[5, 3], [6, 3], [2, 0], [4, 2], [2, 2], [6, 6]]], [[[2, 1], [6, 5], [6, 4], [3, 0], [3, 3], [3, 2]]]`

I would get :

`[[[[5, 3], [6, 3], [2, 0], [4, 2], [2, 2], [6, 6]]], [[[2, 1], [6, 5], [6, 4], [3, 0], [3, 3], [3, 2]]]]`

Thus if I get the list of each player... instead of having this output :
`[[5, 3], [6, 3], [2, 0], [4, 2], [2, 2], [6, 6]]`

I would get : 
`[[[5, 3], [6, 3], [2, 0], [4, 2], [2, 2], [6, 6]]]`

The list `donnes` should be formated as thus `[[],[]]`. Each element represents a player and in its sublist, the list of dominos they hold.

Here's the code.

```
import random

liste_dominos = [[6, 6], [6, 5], [6, 4], [6, 3], [6, 2], [6, 1], [6, 0], [5, 5], [5, 4], [5, 3], [5, 2], [5, 1], [5, 0], [4, 4], [4, 3], [4, 2], [4, 1], [4, 0], [3, 3], [3, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0], [2, 2], [2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]
random.shuffle(liste_dominos)
no_players = 2
if int(no_players) == 2:
    donnes = [[] for i in range(int(no_players))]
    for x in range(no_players):
        donnes[x].append(liste_dominos[:6])
        del liste_dominos[:6]
    print(donnes[0])
    print(donnes[1])
    print(donnes)
```

The print is only there as an indication whether I get the correct result or not. I will be later on using the `donnes` list to perform other operations and thus need to get it in the aforementioned format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

even tho there are better approaches, what is happening is that you are appending to the list what is returned from liste_dominos[:6] as it's, and this is basically a list of the elements contained in that range which are a list returning in fact [ [...],..,[...]]

Using extend to append the inner elements of the list solves this:

```
import random

liste_dominos = [[6, 6], [6, 5], [6, 4], [6, 3], [6, 2], [6, 1], [6, 0], [5, 5], [5, 4], [5, 3], [5, 2], [5, 1], [5, 0], [4, 4], [4, 3], [4, 2], [4, 1], [4, 0], [3, 3], [3, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0], [2, 2], [2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]
random.shuffle(liste_dominos)
no_players = 2
if int(no_players) == 2:
    donnes = [[] for i in range(int(no_players))]
    for x in range(no_players):

        # Changed to extend instead of append
        # It can be changed to += also
        donnes[x].extend(liste_dominos[:6])
        del liste_dominos[:6]

    print(donnes[0])
    > [[1, 0], [6, 5], [4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 3], [5, 5]]

    print(donnes[1])
    > [[5, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [2, 1], [3, 0], [2, 2]]

    print(donnes)
    > [[[1, 0], [6, 5], [4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 3], [5, 5]], [[5, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [2, 1], [3, 0], [2, 2]]]
```

Comment: That works exactly as intended. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `append()` when you actually want `extend()`.

[`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.append): Appends object at end.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.append([4, 5])
print (x)
```

gives you: `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]`

---

[`extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.extend): Extends list by appending elements from the iterable.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.extend([4, 5])
print (x)
```

gives you: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

You want to do

```
donnes[x].extend(liste_dominos[:6])
```

[Original extend vs. append answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/9579589)

Answer (score 0):

You could make same job much easier with list comprehension

```
import random
liste_dominos = [[6, 6], [6, 5], [6, 4], [6, 3], [6, 2], [6, 1], [6, 0], [5, 5], [5, 4], [5, 3], [5, 2], [5, 1], [5, 0], [4, 4], [4, 3], [4, 2], [4, 1], [4, 0], [3, 3], [3, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0], [2, 2], [2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]
random.shuffle(liste_dominos)
no_players = 2
res = [liste_dominos[i*6:(i+1) * 6] for i in range(no_players)]
res
Out[8]: 
[[[2, 2], [4, 1], [1, 1], [6, 0], [4, 2], [5, 3]],
 [[3, 3], [0, 0], [5, 1], [3, 2], [5, 5], [5, 2]]]
```